# Replace values in cells with an integer from a column

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dplyr

If I have a dataframe as follows:

| id | risk | speciesA | speciesB | speciesC | speciesD | speciesE | speciesF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 40 | NA | NA | text1 | NA | NA | text2 |
| B | 12 | NA | text3 | NA | NA | text4 | NA |
| C | 65 | NA | NA | NA | text5 | NA | text6 |

How can I programmatically replace the 'text' values wherever they occur (nb they are likely to be different words in each case) in each row with the value in the 'risk' column so that I get the following?

| id | risk | speciesA | speciesB | speciesC | speciesD | speciesE | speciesF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 40 | NA | NA | 40 | NA | NA | 40 |
| B | 12 | NA | 12 | NA | NA | 12 | NA |
| C | 65 | NA | NA | NA | 65 | NA | 65 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
df[-(1:2)] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(v) replace(v, !is.na(v), v["risk"])))[, -(1:2)]
```

which gives

```
> df
  id risk speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD speciesE speciesF
1  A   40     <NA>     <NA>       40     <NA>     <NA>       40
2  B   12     <NA>       12     <NA>     <NA>       12     <NA>
3  C   65     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>       65     <NA>       65
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C"), risk = c(40L, 12L, 65L),
    speciesA = c(NA, NA, NA), speciesB = c(NA, "text3", NA),
    speciesC = c("text1", NA, NA), speciesD = c(NA, NA, "text5"
    ), speciesE = c(NA, "text4", NA), speciesF = c("text2", NA,
    "text6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to rely on the text starting with "text" in order for it to work, is there a way of replacing any text that occurs with the value from the 'risk' column in that row?

Comment: Just tried it- it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Reshape , replace and reshape back :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('species')) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, risk)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

#  id     risk speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD speciesE speciesF
#  <chr> <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 A        40       NA       NA       40       NA       NA       40
#2 B        12       NA       12       NA       NA       12       NA
#3 C        65       NA       NA       NA       65       NA       65
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("text", x), df$risk, x))
df <- type.convert(df)

# id risk speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD speciesE speciesF
# A   40       NA       NA       40       NA       NA       40
# B   12       NA       12       NA       NA       12       NA
# C   65       NA       NA       NA       65       NA       65
```